# Angular Reactive Form Use a formControl in an other form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I would like to know how I to reuse the formcontrol 'orga'(from registrationForm) in my other formgroup "Pensionform"

```
//Custom validator
 organismeValidator(control: FormControl) {
this.serviceHttp.getAllPensions().subscribe(resp => {
  this.pensionsInvalidite = resp;
  for (let pension of this.pensionsInvaliditesort) {
    if (!pension.dtFin) {
      if (this.registrationForm('orga').value === pension.organisme.code) {  //error : "this expression is not callable
        return { organismeValidator: true };
        break;
      }
    }
  } return null;
})


//Declaration of form groups
this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({
  orga: ['', [Validators.required]],
});
  this.pensionForm = this.fb.group(
  {
    dtDebut: ['', Validators.required],
    dtFin: [''],
    montant: ['', Validators.required],
  },
  { validators: [this.dateValidator, this.organismeValidator] },
);
```

Comment: use `import` and `export`

Comment: Do you mean reuse a single input field?

Comment: Can you develop more please ?

Comment: When you talk about reusability we tend to think about a "big" piece of form, but when I read again it's just a single field? `orga: ['', [Validators.required]]`

Comment: Yes exactly I just want to reuse this piece of form ! And more precisely it value in my other formGroup "pensionform"

Comment: Ok then I understand correctly and my answer is valid, you can create a dedicated component which will encapsulate the field and its validator

Comment: And in this new component I have to implement the definition of  registrationForm and the validators just ? Or the function submit etc ...

Comment: You have to implement 5 functions: `writeValue`, `registerOnChange`, `registerOnTouched`, `setDisabledState` which will define the control behavior, and the 5th function will be a validator which you can name as you want. The submit remains in the main form

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the piece of form in a component that implements [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor). Then you'll be able to use it as if it was a `FormControl`.

For a full working example, take a look at this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m2uzcn)

Comment: And I can't do that without creating another component ?

Comment: After reading your question again, I'm not sure I understand it correctly, but if you want to make a piece of form reusable, the solution is to encapsulate the piece of form in a component, yes